# Request body is an empty object

Tags: node.js, express, redux, rtk-query

My stack is RTK query, Node.js and express.

I have added `app.use(express.json())` as a middlewear but I still just get an empty body. My code below.

This is my apiSlice (RTK query):

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "api",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:3001",
    // credentials: "include",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createRoom: builder.mutation({
      query: (tvId: string) => {
        console.log("Id from action", tvId);
        return {
          url: "/rooms",
          method: "POST",
          body: tvId,
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

When I call create room, I do get a console log with an ID string.

```
this is the id from the action UEP8QtRAcNYr90xCAAAF
```

Then in route, this is my code:

```
router.post("/rooms", async(req, res) => {
        console.log("the tv id is ", tvId);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the console log I get is `the tv id is {}`

My app index file is this:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

require("./db/mongoose");
const roomRouter = require("./routers/room");
const Room = require("./models/room");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const server = http.createServer(app);



const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("get-room", async(roomId, user) => {
        try {
            const room = await Room.findById(roomId);

            if (!room.users.some((u) => u.id === user.id)) {
                room.users = [...room.users, user];
            }
            await room.save();
            socket.broadcast.to(roomId).emit("user-joined", user);
            socket.join(roomId);
            socket.emit("load-room", room);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("failed something", e);
        }
    });
});

app.use(roomRouter);

server.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING");
});
```

So why does the request body keeps coming epmty?

Answer (score 0):

Literally solved it as soon as I've posted. Posting an answer instead of just deleting it in case someone else runs into the same issue in the future.

It seems that the body sent from my front has to be an object, so simply changing this:

```
    return {
      url: "/rooms",
      method: "POST",
      body: tvId,
    };
```

To this:

```
    return {
      url: "/rooms",
      method: "POST",
      body: {tvId: tvId}, // Could also just be written as {tvId}
    };
```

Solved it.